# R: mixed models (lme4), interaction of fixed effects

Tags: r, lme4, mixed-models

Being a novice to R, I am having trouble creating a fixed effects table that presents interactions of the effects. Also, I am not sure is it possible to produce a table that estimates the fixed effetcs? In SPSS, these two are presented in separate tables. 
I'm trying to figure out treatment/location effects on soil respiration in different disturbance classes and different soil layers (the latter is both a random and fixed variable).

I am using lme4 and the formula is:

```
respi.model=lmer(log.respiration.ug.c.c.day ~ location + treatment + 
                 disturbance + layer + (1|layer), data = respiallR)
```

Comment: you need to use * for interaction; e.g. location*treatment

Comment: `a*b` is equivalent to main effects plus interaction (i.e., what we think of as `a + b + a*b`), while `a:b` is equivalent to the interaction alone (what we think of as `a*b`).

Comment: the only situation under which it makes sense to include a predictor as both fixed and random is if the predictor is continuous (i.e. the response can be modeled as a  linear trend) but there are multiple measurements per predictor value, e.g. if the layers were 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 and you wanted to fit both a linear trend and a random effect for the variation around the trend ...

Comment: It's not your R 'novicity' that is a concern here, but rather your statistics na·ive·té. SPSS and SAS are well known for allowing, even encouraging, statistical operations of questionable meaning.

Comment: I'm going to vote to close this as "unclear what you're asking" -- *which* fixed-effect interactions are you interested in?  All of them up to four-way (probably too complex a model, but possible)?  All two-way interactions?  Interaction of `layer` with the other variables?  Can you clarify what you're trying to achieve by having `layer` as both fixed and random (i.e., does my description in my previous comment match your use case)?